# What electronic component does this symbol represent?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, symbol, feedforward

[image: the symbol]

From a schematic of a feed forward converter.

[image]

Comment: Not remotely confident in the guess, but maybe it's an unusual symbol for a current transformer?

Comment: I’d suggest a ferrite bead based on its placement on the diode. Ferrite beads are commonly placed on the lead of a diode to quieten down the transient when a high speed diode snaps on or off.

Comment: The symbol suggests a saturable core inductor, maybe like [this](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/58/b4/38/4a4d847ea0e3b6/US10249716.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol is for a coil with a saturable core.

Comment: thanks all for the valuable comments. this solved my problem.